# Why do I have WooCommerce orders, but no posts of type shop_order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some 30 orders in my shop. I am trying to loop over all orders, but I can't retrieve any orders. Here's the code:

```
$args = array (
            'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
            'posts_per_page'    => - 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    // do some work here
}
```

The loop never runs. I tried printing a count of all post types:

```
$args = array (
        'post_type'         => 'any',
        'posts_per_page'    => - 1
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);    
$types = array();

while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ($types[$type]) $types[$type]++;
    else $types[$type] = 1; 
}

foreach ($types as $type => $count) {
    echo "{$type}: {$count} ";
}
```

This is printing `product: 30 page: 5 post: 1`, i.e. no `shop_order`s. I guess I'm missing something very obvious, but it's not so obvious to me what that obvious thing is!

UPDATE: I am now retrieving all orders with this code:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

That doesn't answer the question though. But it's a solution.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me now. Only a new occurrence. I can't query shop_order posts at all!

Comment: Hope this guide helps: https://wpza.net/loop-for-shop_order-post-type-not-working/ it discusses using `post_status` to show the orders.

Answer (score 8):

use    `'post_status'    => 'wc-processing'` or `'post_status'    => 'any'`